# Conversion operator doesn't work with sleep_until

Tags: c++, std, implicit-conversion, c++-chrono

I try to use a custom class with a conversion operator in a call to `std::this_thread::sleep_until`. Here's the code that I use:

```
class A
{
public:
    ...
    operator std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>() const {
        return std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>{} +
               std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>(timestamp_); }
private:
    std::chrono::nanoseconds timestamp_;
};

A a;
std::this_thread::sleep_until(a); // This doesn't compile (note the overload with time_point).
std::this_thread::sleep_until((std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>)a); // But this does.
```

The compiler error is `error C2664: 'void std::this_thread::sleep_until(const xtime *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'A' to 'const xtime *'`.

Could anybody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong here and how it should be done correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::this_thread::sleep_until` is a function template. During template argument deduction, conversion won't be considered.

Conversion happens *after* deduction is done. Thus your conversion operator has no effect if you don't invoke it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any other nice way around this except the cast or a member function that returns the time_point?

Comment: You could explicitly call `sleep_until<system_clock, nanoseconds>(a)`, but that's not really any better. A named member function is probably easiest.